# How to access data from get request made by a React functional component to localhost server using Axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a MySQL database that contains a list of customers. I am able to access this list from the server side via Express using the following code:

```
app.get("/customer/lookup", (req, res) => {

    const sqlSelect =
        "SELECT * FROM customers;";
    db.query(sqlSelect, (err, result) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(result);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

I can see the JS object data displayed in my terminal, so I know my query is successful. However, I am not able to successfully make a GET request from my front-end React component. This is the code I am using:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function LookupTable() {

    const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=> {
        axios.get("http://localhost:4000/customer/lookup")
            .then(response => {
                setCustomerList(response.data)
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Lookup Table</h1>
            {customerList.map((val)=> {
                return <p>Customer: {val.fullName}</p>
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

export default LookupTable;
```

I am simply trying to render that same JS object data in the browser for now, but I'm only able to render the h1 element. I have tried to console log the customerList within the useEffect function after `setCustomerList(response.data)` and I see that it's an empty object.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your front end looks fine. You need to actually respond with the data from the server--it's not enough just to run a query and log it. Does `res.json(result)` help just below `console.log(result);`? You'll want to handle the bad path by responding with an error of some sort as well, otherwise the connection will time out which is not a good UX for your client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually return the results from you server. Currently you only log them to the console.

Something like

```js
app.get("/customer/lookup", (req, res, next) => {

  const sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM customers;";

  db.query(sqlSelect, (err, result) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(result);
      res.json(result);
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
    }
  });
});
```